# Publish class diagram in VSTS build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a build setup in VSTS and i have a couple of class diagrams that I maintain in my code.

Everytime i run a build, I would like to publish these class diagrams to the TFS project page (dashboard, wiki or home page) for our analysts and testers to review and use.

Is there a simple way to retrieve the diagrams from code after a build and how should i publish these?

Comment: What's with the down vote and no explanation? Seems like a legit, clear, and useful question. I wonder what's wrong?

Comment: I wonder whether the class diagrams could be saved/exported as images and then attached to some Wiki page via the RESTful API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to publish the class diagrams to package page like dashboard, wiki or home page.

For the workaround to show diagram in wiki page:

[Unified Modeling Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language) is not support in wiki markdown, but you can use [yUML syntax](https://github.com/jaime-olivares/vscode-yuml/wiki) to draw yuml diagram correspondingly by yourself.